# Targeting nested div when parent div has multiple classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to target the `block` class in the example below. The issue is that I need to treat each `block` differently depending on whether the parent div has a class of `alignleft` or `alignright`. Anything I try isn't being picked up (Chrome on Mac OS X). I'm unfortunately not able to change the markup.

```
<div class="section alignleft">
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>

<div class="section alignright">
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Currently I'm using the following CSS which **doesn't** work:

```
.section .alignleft .block { float: left; ... }
.section .alignright .block { float: right; ... }
```

However, the following **does** work, but is not useful for me as I need to ensure the `block` is inside the `div` with the `section` class as well.

```
.alignleft .block { float: left; ... }
.alignright .block { float: right; ... }
```

*P.S. Have done quite a few searches but didn't come up with anything which answered this particular question. I'm also not very good with CSS, so any help would be much appreciated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target class only need space others dont want

Make Change your CSS:

```
.section.alignleft .block 
{ 
float: left; 
...
}
.section.alignright .block 
{ 
float: right; 
... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the space between the classes

```
.section.alignleft .block {
   /* Styles */
}

.section.alignright .block {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

So here, am selecting the element having `.block` which is nested under element having classes `.section.alignleft` in first selector and `.section.alignright` in second selector.

This selector which you are using `.section .alignleft .block` will select the element having `.block` which is nested inside an element having `.alignleft` which is further nested inside element having `.section`

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS:

```
.section.alignleft .block { float: left; ... }
.section.alignright .block { float: right; ... }
```

What you where doing before was looking for `.block` in `.alignleft` in `.section`.

Instead you need `.block` inside an element with classes `section` and `alignleft`/`alignright`.